# How can I change foreign key option on MySQL EF 6?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework

I created a table with wrong foreign key option in MySQL EF 6 so I want to change foreign key option of that table to CASCADE DELETE, but how to?

I made this database on code-first. Is there any solution without re-creating database or manually call SQL?

Comment: Do you know how to use migrations at all?

Comment: Do you think so?

Comment: No I don't, seeing your comment below (*i think i have to learn ef migrations*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution. You can customize the migration code using one of this commands

in Visual Studio

```
Add-Migration Changes
```

using PowerShell window

```
dotnet ef migrations add Changes
```

Then you can update the database again.

Here's more [information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#customize-migration-code)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried like below:

public override void Up()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.BoardNoticeContents", "Id", "dbo.boardnotices");

            AddForeignKey("dbo.BoardNoticeContents", "Id", "dbo.boardnotices", cascadeDelete: true);
        }
        
        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.BoardNoticeContents", "Id", "dbo.boardnotices");

            AddForeignKey("dbo.BoardNoticeContents", "Id", "dbo.boardnotices", cascadeDelete: false);
        }

Comment: Dependent table is `BoardNoticeContents` and principal is 'BoardNotices'

but error returned: Table 'sdelight.dbo.boardnoticecontents' doesn't exist

tables are exists, and checked there's no difference between code-first generated 
 table name of foreign key method and my code. i don't know why error returned. could you help me please

Comment: oh now i know 'dbo.' prefix is not needed. i think i have to learn ef migrations. however thanks for reply. it was simple reply, but gave me an idea to how to solve the problem. have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Just change to mapping as it is needed to be

then create migration script as you did it earlier.

```
add-migration AlterMyTableFK
```

after that Update Database as you did it earlier.

```
update-database
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make changes you want, then in the "Package Manager Console", execute this line:

```
add-migration v1
```

note that `v1` in the above line is for migration versioning and you may name the migration anything you want.

To add a new migration that reflects your changes. then execute this line:

```
update-database
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Make changes You Want, Then Open  "Package Manager Console"

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
```

then :

```
PM> Add-Migration v1
```

then:

```
PM> Update-Database
```